# Is there any way to optimize the query while working with 2mil+ rows database table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, collections, mariadb

I am working on Laravel query that shall count the latest month data and also group by week, for the last 3 months. I have tried to fix that in a few ways but still it's exceeds my memory limit and load very slow.
Bellow is the current code that I am using to get the final results - but same problem is also here.

Any idea how to optimize the counting and grouping the data?

```php
$data['pois']['total'] = PoiLocation::whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->year)
    ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
    ->count();

$pois = PoiLocation::where('created_at', '>', (new Carbon)->subMonths(3))
    ->get()
    ->sortBy('created_at')
    ->groupBy(function ($collection) {
        return Carbon::parse($collection->created_at)->isoWeek();
    });

if ($pois->count()) {
    foreach ($pois as $item => $value) {
        $data['pois']['weeks'][$item] = $value->count();
    }
} else {
    $data['pois']['weeks'] = [];
}

if ($data['pois']['weeks']) {
    $data['pois']['high'] = max($data['pois']['weeks']);
} else {
    $data['pots']['high'] = 1;
}
```

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'store_id', 'name', 'address1', 'address2', 'city','state','zip_code', 'dma_desc', 'country', 'lat' ,'lon', 'target', 'is_verified', 'polygons', 'external_id', 'brandID', 'companyID'
];

protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

public $timestamps = true;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your PoiLocation Model and a bit more context to the code you've given that I'm assuming is in a controller

Comment: I have added the Model $fillable to show what data is available.
Also yes, this is Controller and I am calculating and assigned the data to array which is displayed in blade file at the end.

Comment: Thanks... actually looking at it your issue was visible in the original code. You're getting your records before doing your sort and group. You can do these in the DB. The sort is easy using `orderBy(`created_at`)` the group is a little more tricky

Comment: `cursor()` is your friend.

Comment: Just to clarify the end results you're looking for are: Total items created in the last three months, number of items per week in the last three months, and the week with the highest number of items. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LazyCollections`. This should heavily reduce your memory usage.

```
$pois = PoiLocation::query()
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))
    ->orderBy('created_at') // sort in DB instead of wasting more memory doing the sorting.
    ->cursor() // don't load every model in memory
    ->remember() // don't repeat the query (if this line wasn't here, the query would be made 3 times. 1- $poi->all(), 2- ($poi->max() !== null) 3- $poi->max() )
    ->groupBy(function (Poilocation $poiLocation) { // param here is not a collection, it's a Poilocation. Type hint is completely optional
        return $poiLocation->created_at->isoWeek(); // $poiLocation->created_at should already be a Carbon instance because of Eloquent magic.
    })
    ->map->count();

$data['pois']['weeks'] = $poi->all();
$data['pois']['high'] = ($poi->max() !== null) ? $poi->max() : 1;
```

This also simplifies your logic.

- `$poi->all()` will either return an array, empty or not, with the keys.
- `$poi->max()` will return the `max()` of the collection. If the collection is empty, it will return `null`. A simple ternary operator takes care of that part of your logic as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think your main issue is here:

```
$pois = PoiLocation::where('created_at', '>', (new Carbon)->subMonths(3))->get()->sortBy('created_at')->groupBy(function ($collection) {
return Carbon::parse($collection->created_at)->isoWeek();
});
```

You're getting every record created within the last three months, loading them up into your memory and then sorting and grouping. You should aim to do your sort and group operations in the database before getting the records:

```
$pois = PoiLocation::where('created_at', '>', (new Carbon)->subMonths(3))->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

This does the sort by `created_at`in the DB. You group needs a little more thought... Grouping the whole result set in the DB query is proving to be a little tricky.

If you're just aiming to get the count for each week you could use something like:

```
PoiLocation::select(DB::raw("count(*), WEEK(created_at) as week, YEAR(created_at) as year"))->groupBy(['week', 'year'])->get()
```

I think as @IGP suggested, you may not be aiming to actually get the whole set of data so much as just metrics. In that case pushing some operations like the above count by week in the year will help to get the data you need without iterating over every record in memory.

*So to satisfy your original requirements:*

Total items created in the last three months (your original query is fine):

```
$totalPastThreeMonths = PoiLocation::whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->year)
->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
->count();
```

Number of items per week in the last three months:

```
$itemsPerWeek = PoiLocation::select(DB::raw("count(*) as count, WEEK(created_at) as week"))->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->year)
->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)->groupBy('week')->get()
```

And the week with the highest number of items:

```
$itemsPerWeek->sortBy('count')->last();
```

Or:

```
$itemsPerWeek->max('count');
```

I think those would just about get you where you want to be.

Comment: Yes definitely this modification helped a lot! Loading time is decreased for 50% but still high due to grouping

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling a little with the grouping. I'm working on an idea like `PoiLocation::select(DB::raw("id, created_at, WEEK(created_at) as week"))->groupBy('week')->get()` but you have to specify each of the columns on the model and the groupBy isn't quite right

Comment: I think there's a better way to avoid wasting so much memory. As far as I can tell, the results aren't really needed, only the aggregate values. Therefore, calling `get()` and loading all the `PoiLocation` models in memory is a terrible waste (see answer below). Then again, if only the aggregate values are needed, the groupBy should probably be done in the database.

Comment: I think the latest edit should get you there